# discord.py on member join not working or returning error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Ive got this code, but it does nothing.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="Hey there, I'm Robo!")
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} has joined the server.')
    channel = client.get_channel(ChannelId) # i enter my channel id
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Welcome", description="Welcome to the server, " + member, color=999)
    embed.set_footer(text="A footer")
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

But the code does nothing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since a recent update, to receive the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent (wich contains `GUILD_MEMBER_ADD` event) you will need to enable it. To do so:

1. Visit [discord.com/developers/applications](https://discord.com/developers/applications)
2. Click on the bot where you wish to enable privileged intents
3. Navigate to the "Bot" tab on the left
4. Scroll to the Privileged Gateway Intents section
5. Enable your desired intents (in this case SERVER MEMBERS INTENT)

Comment: It doesn't even start the function. On the `print(f'{member} has joined the server')` does nothing either

Comment: Try `intents = discord.Intents.all()`